# Start each task of an usability test in the homepage of the system?

Tags: usability-testing

I need to do some usability tests but Im with a doubt.

I have 5 tasks for the participants of the test execute in a system that has an administrative panel for users insert posts but also there is a front end where the user can access his inserted posts, edit his account, etc.

Is ok to start each test in the homepage of the system? Because if the test starts in some page that already turns the task mor easy to the participant maybe the test is not so effective. And like that starting always maybe is better to test if the navigation of the system is good. Do you know if start each test in the homepage of the system is correct or there is some more correct way to do the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to test: If you're interested in whether your users find their way from the homepage to the place where you want them to do something, you should start from the homepage. If you have a larger process broken down into a few tasks, you might continue the second task from where you left the first.

Be sure, however, that you can easily and quickly get to the starting point of each task. Sometimes users get completely lost in one task and mess up the prototype/system by clicking everywhere. In that case, it is important that you can quickly reach the point where you can continue your test, for two reasons: time with your tester, and avoidance of giving the tester the impression that he messed up so bad that you struggle to get him back on track. (That'll have an effect on his confidence for the next tasks.)